# what is sql query for having,group by in inner join

Tags: php

```
select p.id,
    p.name,
    p.phone,
    count(phone) as times
from passengers as p
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT l.pickup_time, l.passengers_id
    from passengers_log as l
        ON p.id = l.passengers_id
    GROUP BY p.phone
    HAVING Count(phone) > 1
)
```

i recieve this error
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON p.id=l.passengers_id GROUP BY p.phone HAVING Count(phone)>1)' at line 1"

Comment: This query is a mess, even after editing.  You're missing an `ON` clause for the outer query, and I can't figure out what the subquery is supposed to be doing.

Comment: `ON` has to be part of a `JOIN` clause, you can't put it after `FROM`.

Comment: Why are you joining with `passengers_log` in the subquery but not selecting any of those columns in the main query?

Comment: Could you show some sample data and the result you're trying to get? The question is very unclear.

Comment: I use this query=select * from passengers as p JOIN passengers_log as l on p.id=l.passengers_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all you want to do is count the duplicate records in a table.
Try this.
`SELECT   col, COUNT(duplicate_col) AS duplicate_count
FROM     TABLE
GROUP BY col
HAVING   COUNT(duplicate_col) > 0
ORDER BY COUNT(duplicate_col) DESC`